# Возможно ли проверить если внутри li блок ul на js?

Tags: javascript

мне нужно проверить если ли внутри блока li блок ul и если его нету то выполнить действие

Comment: при каком событии проверить?

Comment: просто при загрузке страницы

Answer (score 0):

```
var element_li = ...;
if (!element_li.querySelector("ul")) {
  // нету
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery решение:

```
var hasUl = $('li').find('ul');
if(!hasUl){
    //li не имеет ul
}
```

js решение:

```
var li = document.getElementById('idOfLi');
var hasUl = li.getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0;
if(!hasUl){
    //li не имеет ul
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - дернуть `querySelector('li')` у нужного `ul` и посмотреть на результат

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var id = document.getElementById('sel').value;
  var ul = document.getElementById(id);
  if (ul.querySelector('li'))
    console.log('Have item');
  else
    console.log('Empty');
});
```

```html
<ul id="ul-1"></ul>
<ul id="ul-2">
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<select id="sel">
  <option>ul-1</option>
  <option>ul-2</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Test</button>
```